Cannot print whole notebook from Colab into PDF manually through Colab menus
Not long ago I could print a python notebook from Google Colab using File/Print/Save as PDF. Since about a week I noticed, that only the some part of the document (visible or around the actual cell) is printed only. Same goes for other printing options. I am wondering what is the reason for that and how this problem could be solved.
I tried alternatives (download into jpynb and turn into PDF from Jupyter) however this is more tedious and some formatting is lost.

This question is similar to: Google Co-laboratory notebook PDF download. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I want a short and simple manual solution to do the pdf conversion, that is through the available menus in Colab. Beside, this functionality using File/Print/Save as PDF was working well not long time ago. And am asking for the reason, why this is not functioning properly. Also, notebooks cannot be edited in the same time in Colab and Jupyter, that is text formatting in Colab is lost when editing in Jupyter.

What you are describing is equivalent to pressing Ctrl+P to print and save a webpage as a PDF. This approach is not consistent and is browser-dependent. For example, if you try the same thing in Chrome vs. Firefox, the results can (and will) vary depending on the content. If you want a consistent result, look for a consistent approach.

I just realized, the print on both sides option in the print was selected, this was the reason, the usual print didn't function. So the question has been solved, please close the issue.

I was in same boat, after some research I was able to create pdf in google colab
Steps:

Create a new google colab notebook
Code Cell 1
File id is bold part(masked with xxx for privacy, you need to change this) from the sharable link (anyone with link)
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/**1xxFcxx8Fbxxx4WxxxA4xp**?usp=sharing


file_id = '1xxFcxx8Fbxxx4WxxxA4xp'
output_file = 'File_Name.ipynb'


Code Cell 2


output_file = '/content/' + output_file
html_file = output_file.split('.')[0]+'.html'
pdf_file = output_file.split('.')[0]+'.pdf'

!gdown -q -O $output_file $file_id
!jupyter nbconvert --log-level=50 --to html $output_file
print("HTML file created, Creating PDF file...  ", end="")

!apt-get -qq install wkhtmltopdf &> /dev/null
!wkhtmltopdf $html_file $pdf_file
print("Done.")


In first code cell you are defining variables and in second code cell process is happening.
!gdown -q -O<output_fileName> <file_id>: download ur file in google colab in quite mode.
!jupyter nbconvert : converts ipynb file to html(pdf is not working).
Rest is self explanatory
